# Android Studio 3.0.1 grade syncing getting this com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0, android-multidex

Android Studio 3.0.1 IDE
Am trying to add an aar in my project. that time, am getting this error.. 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.More than one file was found with OS independent path 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/xmlsecurity_de.properties'
again i have fixed for the above with help of packageOptions in build.gradle android{} file added.

packagingOptions {
        exclude 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/log4j.properties'
        exclude 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/schema/xenc-schema.xsd'
        exclude 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/config.dtd'
        exclude 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/schema/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd'
        exclude 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/schema/xenc-schema.rng'
        exclude 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/schema/xmldsig-core-schema.dtd'
        exclude 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/schema/etsi.xsd'
        exclude 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/xmlsecurity_en.properties'
        exclude 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/xmlsecurity_de.properties'
        exclude 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/schema/xmldsig-core-schema.rng'
        exclude 'org/apache/xml/security/resource/config.xml'
        //pickFirst 'org/apache/xml/security/resource*//**' // add this
        pickFirst 'signer.crt'
    }

```
But, again, am getting  this exception.
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

```
I have tried clean and rebuild it. but, unable to use. any help on this situation.

Thanks Advance
```